# dynamic datatemplate binding in WPF datagridcolumn

Tags: wpf, dynamic, datagrid, datatemplate

i have a datagrid having a column of status. by default it'll display a textblock and the text property is binded with the viwemodel's status property.

when the status get changed from status1 to status2 the textblock should be converted to a hyperlink.

how to implement dynamic datatemplate binding to resolve the purpose described above?

Comment: You could use a DataTrigger for TextBlock/Hyperlink control visibility within the Template or a TemplateSelector for the Template.